# Deadlock situations

Tags: operating-system, database-deadlocks

In a given set of processes if some of them can be executed and rest can't because of resources they are requesting for are being held by some other processes. Do we call such a situation as deadlock?

Comment: please read ```https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask``` this before asking a question

Answer (score 0):

A deadlock situation occurs when none of the process's requests is fulfilled. Each process will be in circular wait, waiting for resources held by other processes.

Necessary Condition for deadlock is

1. Mutual exclusion
2. Hold and wait
3. No pre-emption
4. Circular wait

Here in this situation, some processes can execute and rest are not able to, so the processes that are not allocated resources will surely be in circular wait.

Hence so this situation can't be called clearly a deadlock situation.

You can go thorugh Operating systems text book by ABRAHAM SILBERSCHATZ (Wiley) 'The Dinasour Book'.